# Webpack fileloader removes quotes in url path

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I am using the webpack fileloader to copy all of my used webfonts to the dist directory with the following config:

```
   {
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: `[name].[ext]`,
          outputPath: cfg.FONTS.output_dir,
          // useRelativePath: true,
          // publicPath: (x) => '\'/'+x+'\''
      },
    }
```

The problem is, that the output of my css file results without any quotes in the url() part. Like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSans;
  src: url(/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.woff2) format("woff2"),url(/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-italic.woff) format("woff"),;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: "italic"; }
```

How can I force webpack/fileloader to include quotes in the url part?

Comment: Did you figure out what's happening here? I have the same problem.

Comment: It seems to be when you use a relative path it will remove the quotes but if you use an absolute path it will keep them.